# Wordpress blog post url on category page

Tags: php, customization

My Wordpress theme (Big Point) allows me to showcase a list of posts by category.

I have set the format of my posts with a 'documents' category to all be 'links' and when I choose the 'link' format the page displays a URL field which I populate with a link to a PDF.

When I visit the page in the front-end that lists the posts with the 'documents' category I want the href to point to the URL entered into the URL field rather than taking me to a single post page where I then have to click the link to access the file. I want to skipp the middle step.

On the content-single-link.php page the code that displays the link is as follows:

```
<?php $ptype_link_url = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'lolfmkbox_link_url', true); ?>
<h1 class="entry-title"><a href="<?php echo $ptype_link_url; ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
<?php lollum_header_posts($ptype_link_url); ?>
```

I'd like to utilize this code on my block-blog-list.php page. The code on this page that links to the single blog post page is:

```
<a class="news-link" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php printf(esc_attr__('Permalink to %s', 'lollum'), the_title_attribute('echo=0')); ?>" rel="bookmark">
<?php $categories_list = get_the_category_list(' '); $cat = get_the_category(); ?>
<p class="entry-title news-title"><?php the_title(); ?></p> 
</a>
```

How would I declare the variable $ptype_link_url on the block-blog-list.php page?

The function that loops through the records starts like this, defining some variables. I've added $ptype_link_url but it does not appear to register:

```
function lolfmk_print_blog_list($item) {
    $header_text = lolfmk_find_xml_value($item, 'header-text');
    $blog_type = lolfmk_find_xml_value($item, 'blog-type');
    $post_category = lolfmk_find_xml_value($item, 'post-category');
    $blog_number = lolfmk_find_xml_value($item, 'blog-number');
    $ptype_link_url = lolfmk_find_xml_value($item, 'lolfmkbox_link_url'); //***
    $p_image_url = lolfmk_find_xml_value($item, 'lolfmkbox_p_image_url');
```

And the loop starts as:

```
$post_query = new WP_Query($args);
$counternews = 0;
while($post_query->have_posts()) : $post_query->the_post(); $counternews++; ?>
```

I presume I need to use $post_query->the_post() to somehow get and declare the 'lolfmkbox_link_url' URL value. 
Assistance greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have a `$post` object to use `$post->ID`, so use `get_the_ID()` instead. In your loop:

```
<?php $ptype_link_url = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'lolfmkbox_link_url', true); ?>
<h1 class="entry-title"><a href="<?php echo $ptype_link_url; ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
```

Reference: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_ID